# EditingToolbar interferes with the SelectFeature Control - OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, geolocation, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers and I'm having a problem with select feature functionality:

When there is an EditingToolbar added to the map, the SelectFeature control isn't working properly. It doesn't select the feature, it can only highlight it.

I guess that's because the click of the DrawFeature Control and the SelectFeature Control interfere.

The only solution I managed to come up with is to deactivate the EditingToolbar.

This is the eaxmple that I use to find a solution to the problem. I simply add an EditingToolbar to the map from my console and try to debug from there:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/highlight-feature.html

How can I solve this problem without deactivating the EditingToolbar?

Thank you for your time and kind concern.

Comment: okay thanks
ill go over my questions to specify the answers that were most helpful.

Comment: the way i figured out how to do it is to do:
editing_toolbar.controls[2].deactivate();
now i can select the features that i need.
Ofcourse, editing_toolbar is the reference to the EditingToolbar object and the control is chose that random, in reality you need to check all controls and find the one that is active, and then deactivate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I figured out how to do it is to do:

```
editing_toolbar.controls[2].deactivate();
```

Now I can select the features that I need.

Of course, `editing_toolbar` is the reference to the `EditingToolbar` object and the control is chosen at random; in reality you need to check all controls and find the one that is active, and then deactivate it.